# python pandas - yahoo stock data reads into standalone df but not a panel item (which = df)

Tags: python, pandas, io, datareader, yahoo-finance

for some reason, I can get data into a standalone dataframe, but not a dataframe (item) within a panel.

```
df = pd.Dataframe()
df = pandas.io.data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', '2015-09-23', '2015-09-30')

pan = pd.Panel()
pan['AAPL'] = pandas.io.data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', '2015-09-23', '2015-09-30')
```

Running df yields the below stock data, but pan['AAPL'] returns an **empty** dataframe.

```
Date            Open            High            Low         Close           Volume          Adj Close
9/23/2015   113.629997  114.720001  113.300003  114.32          35645700    114.32
9/24/2015   113.25          115.5           112.370003  115         49810600    115
9/25/2015   116.440002  116.690002  114.019997  114.709999  55842200    114.709999
9/28/2015   113.849998  114.57          112.440002  112.440002  51723900    112.440002
9/29/2015   112.830002  113.510002  107.860001  109.059998  73135900    109.059998
9/30/2015   110.169998  111.540001  108.730003  110.300003  66105000    110.300003
```

Shouldn't a standalone df and a df which is an item inside a panel have the same possibilities ?

Update:

I am able to get the data into a dict with keys = a list of stocks, but i get the feeling that perf will slow down more quickly than if the data were housed in a panel.